# How did a Captive Portal force to open a browser

Tags: ios, browser, wifi, mobile-safari, captivenetwork

I've setup a Captive Portal with dd-wrt, wifidog, authpuppy and some plugins from authpuppy as well as my own web app.

1. I am wondering what's the exact **thing** that will **trigger a
   browser** on the client device to **popup**?
2. Is the popup browser from iPhone/iPad a regular browser mode?

   - It seems some JavaScript will fail on the browser mode, like the **shake.js**, 
     event though iOS Safari version is > 4.2.1 from https://github.com/alexgibson/shake.js/

### P.S.:

I've done the research like

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal
- https://personaltelco.net/wiki/CaptivePortal

they don't talk much about the popup browser.

Could anyone help?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ffXuwy_Azs

Answer (score 5):

If you will try to see the network statistics [request/response] you will find out that devices like ios and android both of them continuously hits some particular urls [in case of android it is [www.google.com/generate_204](http://www.google.com/generate_204) , don't remember exact url for ios]. These url are generated by system internally. These pings let their server know about various details. So as soon as ios gets connected with a captive portal it tries to hit the system generated url, failing to which it understands that this is packet level protected network and open the browser.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I have read more how ios would popup while searching with the keyword "CaptiveNetworkSupport/1.0 wispr"
and ios using http://www.apple.com/library/test/success.html. while microsoft using http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt
and the popup flow just like you answered, here is another link about this
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48121/apple-captive-portal-detection-does-not-pop-up-web-sheet-browser

Comment: This is embrassing since you only answered one of my questions. I could only give you an upvote. I don't know how to accept an answer for half , but thanks anyway...

Comment: Well i never asked for an upvote. But as you did, i am thankful. I tried best of my knowledge to help you with the problem you were facing. Sorry if it wasn't that helpful. But would also like to know the meaning of your "half answer" comment.

Comment: Hi Streak, I have same problem, I have created hotspot programmatically, now I want to authenticate by captive portal Means when any person(device) access my(app) hotspot, must show a web page by which they can authenticate/access.
Is there a way to build on top of a WEP Wifi configuration a Captive portal? The hotspot is started using my code(app). How to programatically create and read WEP/EAP WiFi configurations in Android?
The idea is to ask a user for a login before actually sharing the data connection.

Comment: Hi @ACE, please see my issue, if possible give me few clue for solution. I think you have got solution.

Comment: @RamS : are you trying to build a captive portal ?? correct me if i am wrong. If Yes, you should see this link >> http://www.andybev.com/index.php/Using_iptables_and_PHP_to_create_a_captive_portal

Comment: @Streak, Thanks for responding, but can you explain some coding part that where I have to implement this code.

Comment: @RamS: just like it is redirecting to a php page you can use any scripting language [php, jsp, asp, python] and create a login page or signup form.

Comment: @Streak: I want to know where(in coding) I have to put redirecting code, actually I didn't get activity where accept action is performing, if you don't mind, can i share some coding part what i have implemented for hotspot, I am not getting, where i have to redirect any domain.

Comment: Yes, they try to hit a url - but what 'response' does the code expect or not expect to decide "yes" this is a captive portal or no it is not? Just going to a url may produce the response desired, some other response, failed response, redirect response, no response, no network, etc. Which (combination?) makes the code decide it is an active portal then how does it decide where to open a browser to?